# vscode: Debugging Vite App served from Docker (no sourcemaps)

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, debugging, vite, source-maps

I have a (react) vite app running in dev-mode, served from a docker container (I know...)

The src directory on the host machine is mounted into the container. The container exposes the vite-dev-server on `localhost:2222`, vite server `host` option is set to `true`. Everything is working fine including hot reloading.

But debugging in vscode is *not really* working!

Here is my `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Client (Launch)",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            // "url": "http://localhost:5173", // vite dev server running on host machine
            "url": "http://localhost:2222", // vite dev server running in docker container
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/client"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can set breakpoints, start the debugger from vscode, a new Chrome is opened BUT obviously something is wrong:

[image]

In the image above, a breakpoint was set in App.js on line 14 (left side), the file vscode opens for debugging (right side) is not transformed and the halted line 14 does not match with the source.

Debugging works as expected though when I skip docker and launch *vite dev mode* directly on the host machine! So there is probably something missing in my `launch.json` for this special docker scenario. I hope somebody has an idea...

Thanks in advance :)